# Simple Rails code. What is prettier?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Which do you think is prettier and cleaner ?

1)

```
subscription && subscription.update_attributes(subscription_hash)
subscription
```

2)

```
subscription.tap { |s| s && s.update_attributes(subscription_hash) }
```

3)

```
subscription.tap do |sub|
  sub.try(:update_attributes, subscription_hash)
end
```

4)

```
subscription.try(:update_attributes, subscription_hash) ? subscription : nil
```

Please vote or something ...

Comment: I like 3 but this isn't really the place for subjective questions like this.

Comment: It's probably okay to ask how to write this in a clean and concise way, but don't ask for opinions or votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say #1

```
subscription && subscription.update_attributes(subscription_hash)
subscription
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say #4

```
subscription.try(:update_attributes, subscription_hash) ? subscription : nil
```

It's just a lot easier to read and understand imo

Answer (score 2):

I would use #1 because of its straightforwardness or #4 because it's a reasonably readable one-liner.

@Stefan - your code is nice, but not valid. It will fail for `subscription == nil`, which seems to be important for this question

Comment: but could be rewrote as `subscription if subscription.try(:update_attributes, subscription_hash)`

Comment: For confused individuals: the Stefan's answer which I was referring to does not exist any more

Comment: I've undeleted my post

Comment: @knarewski that should be a comment to my answer